# How to export a matrix in a `.txt` file?

Tags: matrix, export

I have the following matrix:

```
\!\(
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "3"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "5"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "7"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "9"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "11"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "13"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "15"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "17"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], 
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "19"]}], 
SqrtBox["2"]]}], "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
       "0"},
{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox["1", "2"]}], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "5"], " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], "2"]}], 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox["1", "2"]}], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "9"], " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], "2"]}], 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox["1", "2"]}], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "13"], " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], "2"]}], 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox["1", "2"]}], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "17"], " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], "2"]}], "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{
RowBox[{"-", 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"-", "1"}], "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "9"], " ", 
SuperscriptBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", "\[Pi]", "+", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "2"], "+", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "3"]}], ")"}], "2"]}], 
RowBox[{"2", " ", 
SqrtBox["2"]}]]}], 
FractionBox[
RowBox[{
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "17"], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "2"]}], ")"}]}], 
RowBox[{"2", " ", 
SqrtBox["2"]}]], "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
       "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{
RowBox[{
FractionBox["1", "4"], " ", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "17"], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", "\[Pi]"}], ")"}], " ", 
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", "+", 
SuperscriptBox["\[Pi]", "2"]}], ")"}]}], "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
       "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"},
{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0",
        "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Center}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.7]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}}], "", ")"}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\)
```

It derives from the folowing code

```
Table[Integrate[psijn[x]*f[x], {x, 0, Nsteps}], {j, Nsteps}, {n, 
   Nsteps}] // MatrixForm
```

I would like to export the matrix in a `.txt` file. I tried with

```
dat=Table[Integrate[psijn[x]*f[x], {x, 0, Nsteps}], {j, Nsteps}, {n, 
   Nsteps}] // MatrixForm
Export["test.dat", dat]
```

but in the folder i got no file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not give definitions for the variables you are using, so I made some up.  Your code should be complete and self contained.

Also you do not want to export the `MatrixForm` as it is a wrapper.  You can do this. Notice the extra `(...)` around `dat=` this is to prevent `MatrixForm` getting into the `dat` variable.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
psijn[x_] := x
f[x_] := x^2;
Nsteps = 5;
(dat = Table[Integrate[psijn[x]*f[x], {x, 0, Nsteps}], {j, Nsteps}, 
     {n, Nsteps}]) // MatrixForm
Export["test.dat", N@dat]
```

Now the file looks likes this

[image]

ps. I added `N` on the data. If you do not want that, you can remove it.

> but in the folder i got no file.

Did you add `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]` ? Otherwise the file will be saved to your  default home folder `$HomeDirectory`, which depends on the OS where that is located.